# How to implement mutex lock using overloaded functions

Tags: multithreading, c++11, overloading

While learning C++ and multi-threading, I came across the question about how to lock a shared function which is called by several threads. I understood that [mutex object](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/mutex/) will do the work for me. If mutex object lock is used on recursive functions, it will create a dead lock - clear. Also there is a special [recursive mutex object](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/mutex/recursive_mutex/) available for such cases - also clear.

Now I have a set of overloaded functions to prepare data for a sub function. Those overladed function will be called by other threads.

I having problems to find an answer to what is the right way to implement mutex lock.

Example: Mutex lock is only on "`Bar()` executing" function `Foo(int, int)`. Other `Foo` functions will call `Foo(int, int)`, but missing lock in its own.

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

std::mutex m; 
std::thread th;

void one_of_many_threads(void) {
  // Will call one of the Foos ... who knows ...
}

bool Foo(int a, int b) {
  bool result;
  // Lock for others ...    
  m.lock();
  // Do some checks on a and b before sending to Bar.
  // We assume everything is fine ...
  result = Bar(a, b);
  // Unlock for others ...
  m.unlock();
  return result;
}

bool Foo(int a) {
  return Foo(a, 0);
}

bool Foo(void) {
  return Foo(0, 0);
}

bool Bar(int a, int b) {
  // Some magic actions with a, b to modify something ...
  // will return true for now:
  return true;
}
```

**Question 1:** Will lead this to issues when `Foo();` or `Foo(1);` called by multiple threads? Those don't have a lock, could be called and then ending up into a lock ...

**Question 2:** Because `Foo(int, int)` could be also called, using mutex lock on all `Foo` functions will make recursive mutex object necessary. But if answer to question 1 would be "No issues!", would it make sense to implement mutex on `Bar(int, int)` function?

Thank you for any answer.

Comment: I do not see any reason to use mutexes there in this example, unless you do some magic in Bar by writing to a class member, and reading the class member by another thread... If so, mutex in Bar should be enough. Try to write more detailed sample code.

Comment: Why not put the mutex in `bool Bar(int a, int b)` instead? Usually, you want mutexes to be as local as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Question 1: Will lead this to issues when Foo(); or Foo(1); called by multiple threads? Those don't have a lock, could be called and then ending up into a lock

No, because both Foo functions only call the

```
bool Foo(int a, int b)
```

which already has a mutex wrapped around everything except “result”. And since result 
is a local variable, it won’t cause data race among different threads

> Question 2: Because Foo(int, int) could be also called, using mutex lock on all Foo functions will make recursive mutex object necessary. But if answer to question 1 would be "No issues!", would it make sense to implement mutex on Bar(int, int) function?

If Bar can only be called through the Foo functions, then there is no need to put an additional mutex in Bar since Bar is already inside the mutex in Foo.

If Bar can be called anywhere freely (and if it accesses/modifies some global/shared resources), then yes, you'd better put a mutex(i.e. a different mutex object, or a recursive_mutex as you mentioned) to prevent race conditions (and deadlock from Foo).

However, there are only local variables in your current example. And if you are only going to work with local objects/copies, there is no need for any mutex at all.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I will mark this as helpful. To consider also comment of @Dom and @Phil1970 at my question above: It makes sense to put mutex object at `bool Bar(int a, int b)` to have it as local as possible.